# One's Complement Arithmetic n C

Tags: c, udp, checksum, ones-complement

I was trying to calculate the checksum of a UDP datagram in C.
In order to calculate the UDP checksum, you create a pseudo header, prefix it to the datagram, and then compute the 16 bit one's complement of the one's complement sum of the pseudo header and datagram.

In order to calculate the one's complement sum, I thought that maybe this would work:

```
~((n + k) - 1) // Where n and k are unsigned 16 bit integers.
```

Would this give me the result of computing a one's complement addition between n and k?

Thank you.

EDIT:

Here's the code for the UDP checksum:

```
   uint16_t compute_udp_checksum(IP *ip, UDP *u,
        void *data, int data_len)
   {

    PSEUDO_HDR *ps = NULL;
    void *buffer = NULL;
    uint16_t sum = 0, *arr = NULL;
    int size = UDP_SIZE + PS_SIZE + data_len;

    ps = create_pseudo_hdr(ip, u); // Create the pseudo-header.
    if (!ps) // If the pseudo header is not allocated, exit.
            return 0;

    if (size % 2) // If the size is not a multiple of 2,
            size += 1; // then add 1 to do so.

    buffer = malloc(size); // Allocate memory to the buffer.
    if (!buffer) // If the memory is not allocated, exit.
     {
            perror("malloc");
            free(ps);
            return 0;
     }

    memset(buffer, 0, size); // Clear the memory.
    memcpy(buffer, ps, PS_SIZE); // Copy the pseudo header.
    memcpy(buffer + PS_SIZE, u, UDP_SIZE); // Then, copy the UDP header.
    memcpy(buffer + PS_SIZE + UDP_SIZE, data, data_len); // Finally, copy the data.

    arr = (uint16_t *) buffer;
    int i = 0;
    while (i < size) // Loop through the buffer.
     {
            sum = ones_complement_add(sum, ones_complement_add(arr[i], arr[i + 1])); // Perform a one's complement addition.
            i += 2; // Go to the next pair.
     }

    /* Deallocate memory to the pseudo header and buffer. */
    free(ps);
    free(buffer);

    sum = ~sum; // Take the one's complement of the sum.
    return sum;
```

Comment: No.  Let `n=1` and `k=2`, the sum should be 3.  `~((1 + 2) - 1)` is not 3.

Comment: To properly calculate the sum of 2 one's complement numbers as part of a step to form a checksum, code needs to have a defined "what to do on overflow".  Overflow will certainly occur with a UDP datagram checksum.  What to do on overflow is not defined as part of the integer encoding.  There are a number of choices.  Of course all OP cares about is how to handle overflow is one's complement with UDP checksum.

Comment: Thank you. If anything, that should've been obvious :)

Comment: See [Ones' complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ones%27_complement#Basics) and try `uint32_t sum = n; sum +=k; if (sum & 0x10000) { sum = (sum + 1) & 0xFFFF;`.  With some effort simplifications can be had.  Also suggest rather than looking at how to do one add, look at how to do the entire checksum which may be (assuming < 64k elements) as simply as adding the entire datagram  and then `sum = (sum + sum>>16) & 0xFFFF;`  Try posting your code for the entire checksum process - even does not compute correctly.